# How to change TFS user/binding without closing Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have my project in TFS and I am using VS 2010 for development.

When I open the Solution it asks me for the credentials.

Once I connect to TFS I am not able to change user without closing the Solution, I am able to disconnect it but when I again click Connect (Team Explorer) it does not ask me for the credential but take the one I entered initially

This might be not a big issue but I really don't want to close and open Visual Studio to change the TFS user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [post on the TFS blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/08/29/clearing-the-credentials-for-connecting-to-a-team-foundation-server.aspx) addresses this issue. The basic solution is to remove the credentials from the Windows credential cache. You can either do this using the Control Panel (as described in the post) or you could use the [cmdkey](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754243%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command line tool like this:

```
cmdkey /delete:MyTfsServerName
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove TFS credentials from **Windows Vault** to clear and force to ask new TFS credentials in Visual Studio

1. Go to **Control Panel** (**Start -> Control Panel**).
2. Click **User Accounts** ( or **User Accounts and Family Safety->User Accounts** in **Windows 7** Machine)
3. Click **Credential Manager** (or **Manage your credentials**)
4. In **Credential Manager** page, you can see the two type of credentials

   i. Windows Credentials
   ii. Generic Credentials
5. Click on two credentials modify link, click the link **Remove from vault** to remove stored TFS credentials.

Now, When you login into Visual Studio you will be asked to give credentials to connect TFS.

**Note**: Don't forgot to uncheck the option **Remember my credentials** to force to ask credentials for every TFS connections.

Answer (score 0):

**For Visual Studio 2010**

The [link to the TFS blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/08/29/clearing-the-credentials-for-connecting-to-a-team-foundation-server.aspx) worked for me, well, only part of it.  I was using Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010) and could not find the "cache" so all I did was clear the credentials as described in the blog post